# Communication between directives on the same element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got an element that is draggable. When its dragged I want a directive assigned to the *same* element to do some DOM manipulation.

So in other words, the second directive is dependent on draggable functionality which could be implemented in a variety of ways.

How do I get the drag directive to inform the other directive that its doing something? e.g. start drag, stop drag, dragging.

Comment: Look at [Creating directives that communicate](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate)